# Compare n arrays and get the uniques

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Trying to compare an undetermined number of arrays with PHP and get those where the vals are no repeated in any of them:

What I have right now:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array 
        ( [1] => 1072 [2] => 835 [3] => 797 [4] => 586 [5] => 421 [6] => 425 [7] => 517 [8] => 658 [9] => 382 [10] => 369 [11] => 358 [12] => 361 [13] => 364 [14] => 359) 
        [1] => Array ( [1] => 1072 [2] => 835 [3] => 797 [4] => 586 [5] => 421 [6] => 425 [7] => 517 [8] => 658 [9] => 382 [10] => 369 [11] => 358 [12] => 361 [13] => 364 [14] => 359 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [1] => 111 [2] => 835 [3] => 797 [4] => 586 [5] => 421 [6] => 425 [7] => 517 [8] => 658 [9] => 382 [10] => 369 [11] => 358 [12] => 361 [13] => 364 [14] => 359 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [1] => 1073 [2] => 835 [3] => 797 [4] => 586 [5] => 421 [6] => 425 [7] => 517 [8] => 658 [9] => 382 [10] => 369 [11] => 358 [12] => 361 [13] => 364 [14] => 359 )
        [4] => Array ( [1] => 90 [2] => 91 [3] => 797 [4] => 586 [5] => 421 [6] => 425 [7] => 517 [8] => 658 [9] => 382 [10] => 369 [11] => 358 [12] => 361 [13] => 364 [14] => 359 )  
...
```

So what I need to get is just those arrays where none of the numbers are in the others.

The number of array to compare is indeterminate, because is the result of a previous filter of data.

Trying to make something as clean as posible without a bunch of loops. I'm using Laravel as Framework, was trying without success converting to collections too. Would appreciate any idea.

Comment: Give an example input and output you want with just a few array items.

Comment: The input:
$arr[0] = [1,2,3,4,5];
$arr[1] = [16,17,18,20,22];
$arr[2] = [1,6,3,9,5];
$arr[3] = [6,7,8,10,12];

What I need to be the output is:
$arr[2]
$arr[4]

Comment: First, you don't have index 4, where did it come from? Also `$arr[2]` and `$arr[3]` both have 6 how is it unique?

Comment: Sorry, got deleted on edit the answer. In the example im giving, I would need as result just arr[2]

Answer (score -1):

```php
$arrs = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1, 2,3],
    [5,6]
];
    
foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
    if ($arr === array_diff($arr, $arrs)) {
        $results[] = $arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer. The op wants all arrays to be compared together, `array_diff` compares one array with other arrays.